# Как сделать поиск WP ограниченным по посту?

Tags: wordpress

в Wordpress есть поиск. Но если им пользоваться он показывает все все результаты. У меня на сайте есть 2 custom post type. И если к примеру я нахожусь на странице записей одного Post Type, как сделать что бы поиск ограничивался именно этим типом записи, а не искал во всех записи?

Comment: /?s=строка_поиска&post_type=slug_custom_post_type

Answer (score 0):

Добавить скрытое поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value=" <current_post_type> ">
```